# How do I display a view content for a specific user?

Tags: views

There are several views to show the content that is restricted by the page_access module. For now, the view shows all the content. Ideally, it must show the content that the specific user is allowed to see.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set permission for the specific role in view. Check the access in page/block settings

Change the access permission to role, then check the access for the specific roles for view content.

[image]

For example, Restrict View for the authenticated user. So, the users who are belonging to the authenticated user roles can able to access the content, other roles cant access it.